# ajax request passing variable to an other page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this following error, i don't understand why nothing is display in my "div".
I want to display my content of my ticket in a new page called ticket.php in my div "mycontent".

script.js :

```
function displaytickets(){

  var newid = {};


    $("#mylist").empty();
    $("#nbtick").html("");
    $("#mycontent").html("");
    var y = document.getElementById("mySecond").value;

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+y+"/tickets/requested.json",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      cors: true ,
            contentType:'application/json',
            secure: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(""));
            },
            success: function (data){
                for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
                    var mytitle = data.tickets[i].subject;
          var description = data.tickets[i].description;
          var status = data.tickets[i].status;
          var myid = data.tickets[i].id;
          console.log(data.tickets[i]);
          var created = data.tickets[i].created_at;


          var nbticket = data.tickets.length;



                    $("#mylist").append('<li id="newlist" value="'+myid+'" onclick="ticketcontent('+myid+')">'+ mytitle +" #"+ myid+ "---"+status +"---"+created+'</li>')

                }
        $("#nbtick").append('<p>'+nbticket+'</p>');
            },


  });
  $("#idisplay").css("display", "none");


}






    function ticketcontent (newid){
      window.location = "http://localhost:8888/support-cubber/ticket.php";
      // var newid = {};
      // var newid = document.getElementById("newlist").value;
      console.log(newid);
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/"+newid+"/comments.json",
          type: 'GET',
          cors: true,
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType:'application/json',
          secure: true,
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(""));
          },
          success: function (data){


            for (var i = 0; i < data.comments.length; i++) {
            var alldata = data.comments[i].body
            $("#mycontent").append('<p>'+alldata+'</p>');

            console.log(alldata);
            }

          },
      });
      var newid = {};
    }
```

ticket.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Support Cubber</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world !</h1>
    <div id="mycontent">
<p>
</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>


</html>
```

Comment: You need to have your ajax function in the ticket.php page that you are navigating to using window.location.

Comment: #psyLogic i can't moove my function into an other page because i m using a variable in my request which is linked into a previous request (i re-edit my post to show you)

Comment: You have no other choice, you can send the variable as a URL parameter or store it in a cookie and access it in the other page.

Comment: #psyLogic you are right i sent my id in my url and i was able to use it for my ajax request so thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

"#Guillaume#Nouhaud", you need to execute "ticketcontent" function on some event say body onload or form submit or button click. no matter where you have written that.
for e.g:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("button").click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({url: "demoUrl", success: function(result){
            jQuery("#div").html('ajax worked!');
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I re-edit my post to show you that i have my event "onclick" (which called my function) this was what you were saying right ?

Comment: Checked your edited code didnt find any event which calling ajax included function. Until and unless you hit that function by some event, it will not execute. I have just answered you how to get call in script. 
You can checkout this plunkr hope it will solve all your doubts. And if it solves your purpose please mark my answer helpful https://plnkr.co/edit/vadodmQNwKsWHy3em9SI?p=info